# Silverlight 3 with Weborb for Java

Tags: silverlight-3.0, weborb

For some reason, i can not invoke java method deployed under Tomcat/Weborb application. When i run weborb console and invoke the method from there, there is no problem. However when i tried to call from Silverlight 3 client, it does not response at all. There is one possibility which is incorrect service gateway. But i have checked the server path to make sure it is correct. I also tried different approaches to invoke server call such as proxy and class interface mentioned inside weborb documentation. I'm stuck with this problem for two days already and can not progress any further. Is there any common mistake when it comes to this problem? Any help would appreciate.

Cheers,
Khoa Nguyen

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. This is because the gateway mapping is incorrect. For instance, When deploy under weborb, the client use localhost:8080/weborb.wo. However when you deploy underworb, the gateway mapping is now change to something like localhost:8080/weborb/console/weborb.wo something like that. You can see how your request mapped to by run the weborb console and look at the server status as you invoke your java methods.

Hope this help.

Cheers,
Khoa Nguyen

Answer (score 0):

**There is a new WebORB for Java 4.1 release available that fixes this mapping issue.** In addition, the new code generator creates a complete client class library with complex types, enums, bindable model and proxy class for the remote Java service. The release is available here:http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products.html